# How to dynamically change item text color in gridlist with custom adapter?

Tags: android, gridview, adapter

I have the adapter that present list of items. I need to change text color of some items on firstPosition and secondPosition. The data list doesn't change, so I can't use notifyDataSetChanged. How can I do this?

This is the method getView in my adapter

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null){
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.alphabet_item, parent, false);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.letterTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.letter_text);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }
    holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    holder.letterTextView.setText(String.valueOf(alphabetList.get(position)));
    if (firstPosition == position) {
        holder.letterTextView.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent));
    } else if (secondPosition == position){
        holder.letterTextView.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
    } else {
        holder.letterTextView.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorText));
    }
    return convertView;
}
```

the firstPosition and secondPosition I declare as Integer

Comment: Code looks fine. Try to add in `else` statement `holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();`

Comment: i don't think it will change anything. My problem is that method getView isn't call when I call notifydataSetChanged

Comment: Then add `Log.i(TAG, msg); ` in `getView` method.

Answer (score 1):

I didnot get your question exactly. But what I think you need is at "firstPosition" && "secondPosition" you want to set the color.

For this you need to check both the position in same if condition

```
if(position == firstPosition || position == secondPosition){
      holder.txtView.setTextColor(colorId);
}
```

Comment: maybe I explain bad.. sorry. my english isn't very well. about question.. I need to send to the adapter a specific item position, and this item must change it's color. firstPosition and secondPosition define positions for diferent colors. I just find the decision.. to declare ArrayList<Boolean> and change on true on position, and call notifyDataSetChanged

Comment: Then your code looks fine if you want set different color for both positions. Try applying the suggestion given by @dieter_h